# What details should show in sculpting

Tags: texture-painting, sculpting, sculpt

I was sculpting a head and wondering what details could i add on the face. The common details i have seen are wrinkles and some imperfection depending on the reference image. For skin pores, i am wondering is it better to do it in sculpting or texture painting? Below is my reference image.

[image]

From what i see, the details except for skin pores is just the wrinkles on the lips. May i know what are the details i could add based on this reference image, and what are the others common details that is usually achieved by sculpting?

**Thank You so much for helping.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add detail until you get to a point where its so small your computer struggles, or you'd rather just let a texture handle it. Maybe large wrinkles or veins I'd sculpt, and the rest I do with a brush template or while texturing. Certainly around the eye I'd sculpt wrinkles and detail, as no way that can be simply covered by a brush or texture. Basically get the form as much as you can with bone structure, then past that its simply up to how much you need/want to do.

Comment: I see, thanks :D