# Weird Face Snap During Retopology

Tags: snapping

I have apply decimate modifiers on a sculpt and trying to retopology, but i have experienced some weird face snapping while i want to move the vertex as shown in the gif, may i know what may be the problem?

[image: 1]]

Besides, may i know what is the point for applying decimate modifier, or even use some retopology tool like instant meshes before we retopology by ourselves? Because we are going to retopology it anyway so why do we take extra steps to reduce the amount of faces first?

**Thank You so much for helping.**

Comment: *"[What is the point of a decimation, if before we retopology by ourselves.]"* Good question, who said that that was a good idea? Any Sources?

Comment: @moonboots

Are you referring to this snapping setting?

https://imgur.com/MgD4TQV.jpg

Comment: yes it looks good

Comment: @moonboots yea because i was following a tutorial, but i could not proceed because of the vertex snapping problem. Any possible solution for it?

Comment: @Leander

I was watching this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuFwUaS8y1I&t=287s

At 1:18 he mentions that he decimated the mesh, but i just wondering why he does that.

Comment: He doesn't explain it and *you should decimate it* is definitely not always true. If you have no performance problem with your high poly model and are planning on doing a full manual retopology, there is no need for simplification.

Comment: Can you make sure your snapping settings look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpCx6.png).

Comment: @Che Xuian yes sorry, not vertex, face is the right setting

Comment: Yea i changed the setting like leander shows, but it still does not work. Tried to redo it on a new project but also does not work.

Comment: Hi, i found out that if i move to other angles and try for few times, the vertex can be moved without this weird snapping, so i assume this is not a setting problem. Thanks for trying to help, may you response to my another post related to texture painting if possible? Highly appreciate the help from you :D https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176586/what-details-should-show-in-sculpting